# how to get all utc time zone using java

Tags: java

```
package timetest;

import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 *
 * @author techno
 */
public class TimeTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String[] availId = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

      // checking available Ids
        System.out.println("Available Ids are: ");
        for (int i=0; i<availId.length; i++){
            System.out.println(availId[i]);
            System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what you want its working already https://ideone.com/A45yDT

Comment: I want to this formate 
Hello guys,
 I need it,`enter code here`
 this formate `li`st
  (UTC +05:30)Asia/Kolkata
(UTC +06:00)Asia/Dhaka
(UTC +05:30)Asia/Kathmandu
(UTC +05:30)Asia/Srilank
(UTC +08:00)America/los angles
please help me

Comment: @Techno, add more details to your question, it is not clear what issue you are facing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (String id : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
    int offsetHr = tz.getRawOffset() / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    int offsetMin = Math.abs((tz.getRawOffset() / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    System.out.printf("(UTC%+03d:%02d)%s\n", offsetHr, offsetMin, tz.getID());
}
```

`getRawOffset()` method of `TimeZone` returns the offset in milli seconds. From this value, you can compute hour and minute value.

Answer (score 0):

check https://ideone.com/A45yDT

```
for (int i=0; i<availId.length; i++){
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(availId[i]));
    int offsetInMillis = TimeZone.getTimeZone(availId[i]).getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis());

    String offset = String.format("%02d:%02d", Math.abs(offsetInMillis / 3600000), Math.abs((offsetInMillis / 60000) % 60));
    offset = (offsetInMillis >= 0 ? "+" : "-") + offset;
    System.out.println("(UTC "+offset+") "+TimeZone.getTimeZone(availId[i]).getID());
        }
```